# Uninstalling a module in Orchard

Tags: orchardcms

I am trying to uninstall the Designer Tools, but, when I Uninstall, I get a 404 on /Packaging/PackagingServices/UninstallModule.  Is there a way to get that UninstallModule?

Comment: Any particular reason for uninstall over just disable?

Comment: @urbanit:  Our security folks are worried about the code being there.  Might be able to assuage them with the fact that it's disabled, but probably better to be uninstalled, which makes sure it can't ever be enabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Orchard 1.x, uninstalling a module is as simple as deleting its folder under the modules directory. Before you do that, however, disable it just to check the site still runs without it, and also check in the modules admin page what other modules depend on it. In the case of designer tools you should be fine.

Another solution if you want to keep the convenience of debugging easily on your dev boxes but keep your deployed version secure is to modify your deployment procedure to exclude specific modules.